# Javascript: reaching arrays with for

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have three arrays, `a1 = [], a2 = [], a3 = []` and I want to put some values in them from an other arrays `odd[1,3,5]` and `even[0,2,4]` . I want to take some random value from odd then put it a1 and remove chosen number, then same process for the other two array. After that I want to do same thing with even array.

I get the value with math.random, after i find the index with indexOf, i remove the chosen number with splice.  This works but can I shorten the process by using for ?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you showed your code and not just a text description of it.

Comment: *This works but can I shorten the process*, if this post is about improvements/optimizations in an existing working code, CodeReviews is the right place

Comment: No, I was thinking of the same functions.  You can skip indexOf if you really want.  Something like destination.push(source.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()  * source.length) - 1,1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
let aDict = {a1: [], a2: [], a3: []};
const odd = [1,3,5];
const even = [0,2,4]


for(a of Object.values(aDict)){
    a.push(odd.splice(Math.floor((Math.random() * odd.length)),1)[0]);
    a.push(even.splice(Math.floor((Math.random() * even.length)),1)[0]);
}
```

EDIT: Don't think `for of` and `Object.values()` is supported by IE. So if you need IE support you should use `for in` and `Object.keys()`. Might have to do a `hasOwnProperty()` check as well then.